# Histogram not getting displayed from python shell

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Running numpy histogram from python shell but histogram is not getting displayed.

`edges = (pd.DataFrame(edges)).describe()
 np.histogram(speed,bins = edges)`

Output:

`(array([45080507,  1178935,  1014354, ...,      494,      182,       75]),
 array([0.00000000e+00, 4.44437381e-02, 8.88874762e-02, ...,
        6.98211125e+01, 6.98655563e+01, 6.99100000e+01]))`

the output I believe is both the x-axis and the y-axis values in array form. How do I make it display the histogram. I am running it on ipython. I am not using any editors as my input text file is 20 GB big and running it every time would take a lot of time, so coding directly from terminal after I load the text-file once. Help regarding this would also be great, if it is possible to work on a notebook environment (collab or jupyter like) with a large dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function only returns the (x,y)-arrays. Try matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(speed, bins='auto')
```